# Поиск минимального элемента массива в формате h:mm (VBA)

Tags: массивы, excel, vba

Помогите доработать код, чтобы из массива, состоящего из времени и нескольких суток, выводилось в формате h:mm, а не как дробь.
[image: Массив]

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim b(11) As Integer
For i = 2 To 11
    b(i) = Worksheets("Лист1").Cells(i, 2).Value
Next i
s_min = b(2)
For i = 2 To 14
    If b(i) < s_min Then
        s_min = b(i)
    End If
Next i
     MsgBox "Наименьшее значение: " & s_min
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Время - часть суток, 1 сутки - это 1 (единица). Это значит, что время - дробное число <1.

В самом начале процедуры заложена ошибка: `Dim b(11) As Integer` - объявление массива ЦЕЛЫХ чисел. Какое бы время не находилось в ячейках, в массив запишется значение, округленное до целого, т.е. 0 или 1.

Размерность объявленного массива начинается с нуля (`Dim b(11)` - от 0 до 11, 12 элементов), но заполнение в первом цикле начинается с елемента 2.

При заполнении массива из диапазона напрямую размерности начинаются с единицы и массив получает размерность, одинаковую с размером диапазона. Если диапазон данных на листе неразрывен, цикл заполнения массива лишний.

Чтобы вывести результат не дробным числом, а в формате времени - `Format(s_min, "hh:mm:ss")`

Не нужно забывать об объявлении всех используемых переменных.

```
Sub MinTime()
    Dim aTime()
    Dim s_min As Double
    Dim i As Long
    
    aTime = Worksheets("Лист1").Range("B2:B11").Value
    s_min = 1
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(aTime)
        If aTime(i, 1) < s_min Then s_min = aTime(i, 1)
    Next i
    
    MsgBox "Наименьшее значение: " & Format(s_min, "hh:mm:ss")
End Sub
```

Comment: из-за того, что в массиве присутствуют 2 суток, выводится время 1:57 из 2 суток вместо 3:01 в первых, как можно это исправить?

Comment: В вопросе нет ничего о сутках. Нет примера, в котором можно увидеть данные. Сравнивать только время -  без целой части (без суток):  `If aTime(i, 1) - Int( aTime(i, 1)) < s_min Then...`

Comment: *выводится время 1:57 из 2 суток вместо 3:01 в первых* - правильно, 1:57< 3:01

Comment: Это так но в моем случае 3:01 это будет 27:01 от 0:00 1 суток, то тогда 3:01<27:01

Comment: Ничего не понял из последнего пояснения... Уточнение из предыдущего моего сообщения помогло?

Comment: Не совсем, выходит также 1:57. По сути, нужно чтобы вывести самое меньшее время вначале массива, даже если в самом конце будет еще меньше, чем вначале.

Comment: Да что же Вы условия задачи порциями выдаете?! Примера нет, условия по одному за пол-дня, в заголовке - поиск минимального во всем массиве, последнее условие - только где-то вначале.. Да ну... С таким подходом - код перед Вами, думайте, дорабатывайте.